# Uniformity of ultrafilter causing contradiction; Hanf-Scott, Rowbottom theorem

Tags: set-theory, filters, large-cardinals

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 8.30. in the book "The theory of ultrafilters" by Comfort and Negrepontis.

**Theorem.** If $p$ is a normal ultrafilter on a measurable cardinal $\alpha$, then $\{\beta < \alpha : \beta \rightarrow (\beta )^{<\omega}_2\} \in p$.

I will try to summarize the proof leading up to the detail that I do not understand.

The proof goes by contradiction, so it is assumed (after showing that the set of all cardinals smaller than $\alpha$ is in $p$) that $$I=\{\beta < \alpha : \beta \not\rightarrow (\beta )^{<\omega}_2 \} \in p.$$
For every $\beta\in I$, we take a partition witnessing the relation $\beta \not\rightarrow (\beta )^{<\omega}_2 $, and construct from this a partition of $\alpha$. As $\alpha $ is Ramsey, there is some set $A\subset \alpha$, $\lvert A\rvert=\alpha$, that is homogeneous with respect to this partition.

We consider the assumption that $\{\beta \in I : \lvert \beta \cap A \rvert < \beta\}\in p$, and get by normality of $p$ that there is some $\gamma < \alpha$ such that $\{\beta \in I : \lvert \beta \cap A \rvert = \gamma\}\in p$.

Now the book says that this is a contradiction to the fact that $p$ is uniform. This is the part that I do not understand. Why is it immediately clear that $\lvert \{\beta \in I : \lvert \beta \cap A \rvert = \gamma\}\rvert <\alpha$?

Comment: Hint/sketch: the set you mentioned is bounded below $\alpha$, because $A$ is large.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Thanks! I have thought about your hint but I still can't make it work. Can you say a bit more specifically what aspect of the largeness is used?

Comment: By largeness I only meant $|A|=\alpha$. Note that $\gamma^+$, the cardinal successor of $\gamma$, is less than $\alpha$. Since $\alpha$ is regular, there must be some ordinal $\beta<\alpha$ with $|A\cap\beta|\ge\gamma^+$[just pick $\gamma^+$ many elements of $A$, and let $\beta$ be their supremum; by regularity of $\alpha$, this works]. Now you can see that your set is a subset of $\beta$, because above $\beta$, $A$ has many elements. And so your set is bounded.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Thanks for the clarification!